# Why it is returning output as n

Tags: python

I have come across one question during where the person ask me
what is the output of this below code

**Code :**

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'John', 'Daman']
print(names[-1][-1])
```

Then i said the answer will be : `John`

But the person who was interviewing he said the answer is `'n'`

Can some one illustrate how it is `n`

Comment: `names[-1]` gets the last item on the list which is `'Daman'`. Then you get the last letter of that name `'Daman'[-1]` which is `'n'`

Comment: Please run and try the code first.

Comment: If you  want to get "John" use ```print(names[-2])```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[-1][-1]` is not `[-2]` at all.

Take the last word, then its last letter

```
>> names  
['Chris', 'Jack', 'John', 'Daman']
>> names[-1]
'Daman'
>> names[-1][-1]
'n'                # 'n' of Daman
>> names[-1][-2]
'a'                # last 'a' of Daman
>> names[0][1]
'h'                # 'h' of Chris
```

Answer (score 2):

list[-1] means it will take the last element of that list. And list[-1][-1] means it will take the last element of the last element.

So in this case `name[-1]` returns 'Daman', and `name[-1][-1]` returns 'n'.